# How to wrap a C struct in a C++ class and keep the same name?

Tags: c++, namespaces, wrapper

Let's say the Acme company releases a useful library with an extremely ugly C API. I'd like to wrap the structs and related functions in C++ classes.  It seems like I can't use the same names for the wrapper classes, because the original library is not inside a namespace.

Something like this is not possible, right?

```
namespace AcmesUglyStuff {
    #include <acme_stuff.h>   // declares a struct Thing
}
class Thing {
 public:
    ...
 private:
    AcmesUglyStuff::Thing thing;
};
```

Linking will be a problem.

The only way I can think to wrap the library, and not pollute my namespace with the C library names, is a hack like this, reserving space in the class:

```
// In mything.h
namespace wrapper {
  class Thing {
   public:
    ...
   private:
    char impl[SIZE_OF_THING_IN_C_LIB];
  };
}

// In thing.cc
#include <acme_stuff.h>
wrapper::Thing::Thing() {
    c_lib_function((::Thing*)impl); // Thing here referring to the one in the C lib
}
```

Is that the only way?  I'd like to avoid putting prefixes on all my class names, like `XYThing`, etc.

Comment: Warning: Bad idea ahead, proceed with caution! ... What happens if you `#define` the struct name to something else, import the header, then `#undef` the struct name and write your class?

Comment: It is a good habit for perfect C++ interface (in opposition to ugly C interface) to keep it in some namespace. Think of it as good thing - the `namespace PerfectCPPInterface { class Thing {}; }`

Comment: Hopefully modules will be part of the C++ standard some day.  But everybody does it anyway and cleanly solves this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're making this harder than it needs to be.

```
#include "acme_stuff.h" // puts all of its names in global namespace

namespace acme {

class Thing {
public:
    // whatever
private:
    ::Thing thing;
};

}
```

Now just use `acme::Thing` rather than `Thing`.

If it's really important to you to not have the C names in the global namespace, then you need a level of indirection:

```
namespace acme {

class Thing {
public:
    Thing();
    ~Thing();
    // whatever
private:
    void *acme_thing;
};

}
```

In your implementation file, `#include "acme_stuff.h"`, in your constructor create a `new ::Thing` object and store its address in `acme_thing`, in your destructor delete it, and in your member functions cast `acme_thing` to type `::Thing*`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to try to name something the exact same thing as something else.  (I mean equal fully-qualified names, including all namespaces.)  If some library has already grabbed the obvious best name in the global namespace, you'll need to pick a different name.

You could put *your* class `Thing` in a namespace as Pete Becker suggests, and then use `::Thing` to access Acme's `Thing`.  That would be fine if you're prepared to always access your class through it's fully namespace-qualified name (e.g. `My::Thing`).  It's tempting to try `using My::Thing;` or `using namespace My;`, but [that won't work](http://ideone.com/ETyON), because any translation unit that includes the definition of your class (e.g. via a header file you create) must necessarily pull Acme's `Thing` into the global namespace first (otherwise an "Undefined symbol" compilation error would occur when parsing the definition of `My::Thing`).

Answer (score -1):

Is it really a **C** API? Try to `extern "C" {}` to whole included header to solve the linking problem.

```
namespace AcmesUglyStuff {
  extern "C" {
    #include <acme_stuff.h>
  }
}
```

Comment: How `extern "C"` helps to `C` `struct Thing` vs `C++` `class Thing` problem?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Just like what OP has done in the first code block? You use `AcmesUglyStuff::Thing` to refer to the C struct.

Comment: In my little test program this seems to be working, but I'm confused about why.  I expected it not to link, but I guess if the symbols are extern C, then they don't get mangled or wrapped in the namespace.  I may mark this as an answer after more experiments.

Comment: -1 This is a maintenance nightmare. To see why, try the above with `<windows.h`. As a first shot you need to first include the basic runtime lib headers used by the C header (happily for `<windows.h>`, in the old days, that was just four or five), and then you can start tackling, on a version by version basis, typedefs and macros and stuff.